# Issue with rendering HTML elements using a nested map JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a json file which has the required data. And I am looping through the data using .map() and rendering the details within HTML .When I add console statements instead of HTML  I am able to see that the loop is fetching the required data but when I try to render the same in HTML tags I see nothing on the screen.

List.js

```
// import { } from "react-icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function List({ module }) {

    const icons = {
        //icons
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="card my-3 rounded-0">
                {/* Module Header */}

                <div className="card-header px-0 list-group-item-secondary">
                    <div className="btn-group mx-2 align-items-center" role="group">
                        {/* buttons */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="float-end">
                        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">

                            {/* HTML content */}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* Module Items List */}

                {/* If module_items exists display ul */}

                {module.module_items.length > 0 && (
                    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">

                        {/* Loop module_items */}
                        {module.module_items.map(
                            (module_item, idx) => {

                                // Display module_item_name
                                return (
                                    <div key={idx} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
                                        <div className="row list-item-row">
                                            {/* other elements */}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    // Adding {} to check condition(length of array) and then loop through the list gives error
                                    {module_item.module_item_list.length > 0 &&(
                                        module_item.module_item_list.map((module_sub_list_item, i)=>{
                                            return <div>
                                                            // other HTML div to display module_sub_list_item
                                                    </div>                           
                                        })
                                    )}
                                        
                                )
                            }
                        )}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default List;
```

I am currently able to display the "module_item".But, in the commented section when I try to add the following:

```
{module_item.module_item_list.length > 0 &&(
    module_item.module_item_list.map((module_sub_list_item, i)=>{
        return <div>
                     // other HTML div to display module_sub_list_item
               </div>                           
    })
)}
```

The moment I add {} to include any js I get the below errors:

[image]

I have done something similar for the first map but the same is not working in the nested map().

.json file with data

```
[
    
    {
        "course_id": "123",
        "modules_data": [
            {
                "module_header": "Heading 1",
                "module_description": "",
                "module_items": [
                    {
                        "module_item_name": "Item_name 1",
                        "module_item_list": [
                              {
                                "name": "Sub item name",
                                "path": ""
                              }
                         ]
                    },
                    {
                        "module_item_name": "Item name 2",
                        "module_item_list": []
                    }
                    
                ]
            }
        ]
     }
]
```

"module_item_list" can be an empty list in which case only "module_item_name" is displayed.

I am working with JSX for the first time and any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Try wrapping `<div>// other HTML div to display module_sub_list_item</div> ` with parentheses `( )`

Comment: I tried that. but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you please provide a completed example which includes the second loop jsx as well. And try to provide a formatted code, it is very hard to understand it without proper formatting.

Comment: You are missing the fragment in your second loop.

Adding the code in answer for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the react standards, the top most node in your jsx should always be a single node. And in your nested code you are using 2 nodes. Solution for this problem is to wrap the nested loop code in a React Fragment, which doesn't render anything but provides the singe parent node to your elements. But in your case you need to provide the key prop to the root node in second loop. And fragment can not accept any props so it's a better idea to wrap it with an container `div`

I have done one small change in your code and now the error is not there.

```
// import { } from "react-icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function List({ module }) {
  const icons = {
    //icons
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card my-3 rounded-0">
        {/* Module Header */}

        <div className="card-header px-0 list-group-item-secondary">
          <div className="btn-group mx-2 align-items-center" role="group">
            {/* buttons */}
          </div>
          <div className="float-end">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
              {/* HTML content */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Module Items List */}

        {/* If module_items exists display ul */}

        {module.module_items.length > 0 && (
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            {/* Loop module_items */}
            {module.module_items.map((module_item, idx) => {
              // Display module_item_name
              return (
                <div key={idx}>
                  <div
                    className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                    aria-current="true"
                  >
                    <div className="row list-item-row">
                      {/* other elements */}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  // Adding {} to check condition(length of array) and then loop
                  through the list gives error
                  {module_item.module_item_list.length > 0 &&
                    module_item.module_item_list.map(
                      (module_sub_list_item, i) => {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            // other HTML div to display module_sub_list_item
                          </div>
                        );
                      }
                    )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much!!